# Laravel eloquent query relationship with an added column using selectRaw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I started the query like this:

```
$students = StudRegProfile::with(['my_campus','work_experience' => function($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('*, datediff(dateend, datestart) / 360 as years_of_experience');
            }]);
```

**Update:**

My query is now like this:

```
$students = StudRegProfile::with(['my_campus','work_experience'])
            ->withCount([
                'work_experience as years_of_experience' => function($query) {
                    $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(datediff(dateend, datestart) / 360)'));
                }
            ]);
```

Now I have `years_of_experience` as column in work_experience relationship. My output looks like this:

```
[
  id => 1,
  work_experience => [
    id => 1,
    years_of_experience => 2.4417,
  ]
]
```

But when I filter it like this:

```
$students->whereHas('work_experience', function($query) {
  $query->whereRaw('years_of_experience >= 2');
});
```

It can't find my `years_of_experience` column.

Query Log:
[image]

**Update:**

My StudRegProfile `hasMany` work_experience. My work experience has datestart and endstart. I want to get the total difference in datestart and endstart so I can filter it as and input in my form

Comment: look at the query log and you will see why that is the case ... `DB::enableQueryLog(); ... your query ... dump(DB::getQueryLog())`

Comment: can you show me how did you write the relationship?

Comment: @Garry 
```public function work_experience(){
        return $this>hasMany('Modules\Student\Entities\StudentExperience','studentcode','studentcode');
    }```

Comment: @lagbox ok I will try to make this queryLog() work because for now it just returns `null`, and I don't entirely know how to use it

Comment: enable the query log, then run your query, then dump the query log

Comment: @lagbox
like this?
```\DB::enableQueryLog();
        $students = StudRegProfile::with(['my_campus','work_experience'])
            ->withCount([
                'work_experience as years_of_experience' => function($query) {
                    $query->select(\DB::raw('SUM(datediff(dateend, datestart) / 360)'));
                }
            ]);

        dump(\DB::getQueryLog());```

Comment: the output is an empty array

Comment: you are not executing any query there you are just building a query (you have to call `first` or `get` etc to execute the query; get a result)

Comment: thanks a lot I have posted the logs on the update

Comment: so you can see why what you were trying to do doesn't work right?

Comment: yeah apparently this line in the log ```(select SUM(datediff(dateend, datestart) / 360) from `student_workexp` where `stud_reg_profile`.`studentcode` = `student_workexp`.`studentcode`) as `years_of_experience` ``` only outputs after the query is executed not during